CMFCColorButton dialog color image too dark
Is there a way to brighten the image in the colorpicker dialog so it is useful? Not sure why it is so dark in my MFC CRichEditView related app.

Doesn't seem related to any visual manager I've tried with or without on Windows 10. I see apps like excel or wordpad color image is bright and continuous. I notice the image has repeating black which almost looks like a half-tone. The app on a Windows 10 with 4k monitor just shows a finer pattern. I didn't see any clues to resolve with CMFCColorPickerCtrl class either.

I figured out what the problem was. It was caused by using True in a manifest. Once I removed the manifest, I didn't get stretched half tone images and they look bright!

This led me in that direction as a clue related to GDI https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/halftone-palette-and-color-adjustment
